# Docker/Selenium/Headless Chrome: Configure SUID sandbox correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, docker

I want to run selenium and headless chrome in my docker container for testing purpose.

I have tried to run selenium in headless chrome (outside my docker container) with the following in my .js file. This worked:

```
const client = webdriverio.remote({
   desiredCapabilities: {
   browserName: 'chrome',
   chromeOptions: {
     args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu']
   },
   binary: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
   },
 baseUrl: CONFIG.host,
 logLevel: 'verbose',
 waitForTimeout: 3000
 })
```

But I can't get this to work in my docker container. In my docker container I use "FROM selenium/standalone-chrome". There does not seem to be any problem with my dockerfile. The problem occurs when I try to run my selenium tests. I changed the binary_path in my .js file to /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome. But the tests fails and client can not even be initiated.

So I tried to just run /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome in order to see if chrome works, but then I get this error:

```
[0711/005304.226472:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(311)] NaCl helper 
process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

I am pretty new to this (and stack overflow) so there might be some basic things I have missed.

Answer (score 3):

Try to include `--no-sandbox`

```
chromeOptions: {
  args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--no-sandbox']
},
```

As I'm doing at [docker-selenium](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/blob/3.3.1-p17/Dockerfile#L826)

Comment: i'm getting the same error on a VPS SSH that is running CentOS 7 64-bit when i try to launch Chrome with the `--no-sandbox` parameter (while troubleshooting why my scripts for scraping aren't working online) :/ Not sure what to do.

Comment: @Anthony did you find a solution? I'm exactly in the same place

Comment: @JCarlos i believe i did find a solution, but i cant remember what it was now. sorry :(

Comment: weird, now getting "Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file 
or directory"

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
[1003/144118.702053:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(310)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

...implies that *you have no setuid sandbox* in your system, hence the program was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Solution

The easiest (not so clean) solution is, if you want to run Chrome and only use the namespace sandbox, you can set the flag:

```
--disable-setuid-sandbox
```

This flag will disable the setuid sandbox (Linux only). But if you do so on a host without appropriate kernel support for the namespace sandbox, Chrome will not spin up. As an alternative you can also use the flag:

```
--no-sandbox
```

This flag will disable the sandbox for all process types that are normally sandboxed.

Example:

```
chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--no-sandbox']
},
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Security Considerations - ChromeDriver - Webdriver for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101367/security-considerations-chromedriver-webdriver-for-chrome/60111052#60111052)

---

### Deep dive

As per the documentation in [Linux SUID Sandbox Development](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/docs/linux/suid_sandbox_development.md) [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) needs a `SUID` helper binary to turn on the sandbox on Linux. In majority of the cases you can install the proper sandbox for you using the command:

```
build/update-linux-sandbox.sh
```

This program will install the proper *sandbox* for you in `/usr/local/sbin` and tell you to update your `.bashrc` if required.

However, there can be some exceptions as an example, if your `setuid` binary is out of date, you will get messages such as:

```
NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

Or

```
Running without the SUID sandbox!
```

In these cases, you need to:

- Build `chrome_sandbox` whenever you build chrome (`ninja -C xxx chrome chrome_sandbox` instead of `ninja -C xxx chrome`)
- After building, execute `update-linux-sandbox.sh`.

  ```
  # needed if you build on NFS!
  sudo cp out/Debug/chrome_sandbox /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  sudo chown root:root /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  sudo chmod 4755 /usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  ```
- Finally, you have to include the following line in your `~/.bashrc` (or `.zshenv`):

  ```
  export CHROME_DEVEL_SANDBOX=/usr/local/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox
  ```