# Security Considerations - ChromeDriver - Webdriver for Chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, security, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I was wondering if anyone had more information on what the specific risks for using chromedriver as was concerned by this statement.

"If possible, run ChromeDriver with a test account that has no access to sensitive local or network data. ChromeDriver should never be run with a privileged account."

Would like to know what the specific risks are when using a privileged account and what if any preventative measures can be taken to protect against them.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Chromedriver exists outside of the sandbox, so it's possible something could tunnel out through it.  Running it from a low-privileged account would help if something nasty came through... For remote drivers there is also the risk of someone using it to gain access to browser-stored information or even to hijack an existing browser session...  using a non-privileged account wouldn't help in that case though.  Whatever information is used in the running script would still be vulnerable.

Answer (score 3):

### How Google Chrome Browser Works

In the article [Chrome Browser Security](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/google-chrome-browser7.htm) @STEPHANIE CRAWFORD mentioned, Google has leveraged its power as a search engine by creating its **Safe Browsing** technology which will automatically warn you if Chrome detects that a site you're visiting contains [malware](https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/how-to-tech/how-to-avoid-spyware.htm) or [phishing](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/phishing.htm).

Chrome deploys this security measure through a unique security feature termed as [Sandboxing](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md). Sandboxing implies, separating each process out into independent spaces to see how they function individually. Chrome handles its workload as a series of multiple processes rather than as part of one large browser process. Each time you open a Web page, Chrome launches one or [more new processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57400613/many-process-of-google-chrome-32-bit/57411466#57411466) to run the scripts on that page. Also, each Chrome extension and app runs in its own process. Chrome implements sandboxing through its multi-process architecture. The security advantage in sandboxing comes with Chrome being able to control the access token for each process. These access token for a process allows that process access to important information about your system, like its files and registry keys. Chrome intercepts each access token from the processes launched from the browser, and it modifies that token to limit its access to that information. So, Chrome's sandboxing helps block web pages that try to install malware, capture your personal information or obtain data from your hard drive. The drawback of sandboxing is that, it can't catch everything. A sandboxed process might still be able to access less secure file systems. It's also likely to miss protecting registry keys and files managed by third party software, like a game or chat program that isn't native to the system.

---

### WebDriver driven Chrome

While initiating a [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) controled *Chrome Browsing Context* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) recently we had been advocating to use a certain command line argument:

- [`--no-sandbox`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#no-sandbox): Disables the sandbox for all process types that are normally sandboxed.

See:

- [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50642913#50642913)
- [How to configure ChromeDriver to initiate Chrome browser in Headless mode through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920243/how-to-configure-chromedriver-to-initiate-chrome-browser-in-headless-mode-throug/49582462#49582462)
- [unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed with ChromeDriver Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902507/unknown-error-session-deleted-because-of-page-crash-from-unknown-error-cannot/53970825#53970825)

---

### No Sandbox

There are a couple of more Sandbox related flags available which enables the sandboxed processes to run without a job object assigned to them. This flag is required to allow Chrome to run in RemoteApps or Citrix. This flag can reduce the security of the sandboxed processes and allow them to do certain API calls like shut down Windows or access the clipboard. Also we lose the chance to kill some processes until the outer job that owns them finishes.

- [--allow-no-sandbox-job](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=49): Disables usage of sandbox job.
- [--allow-sandbox-debugging](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=51): Allows debugging of sandboxed processes.
- [--disable-gpu-sandbox](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=55): Disables the GPU process sandbox.
- [--disable-namespace-sandbox](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=58): Disables usage of the namespace sandbox.
- [--disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=61): Disable the seccomp filter sandbox (seccomp-bpf) (Linux only).
- [--disable-setuid-sandbox](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=64): Disable the setuid sandbox (Linux only).
- [--disable-win32k-lockdown](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=66): Disables the Win32K process mitigation policy for child processes.
- [--enable-audio-service-sandbox](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=70): enable the audio service sandbox.
- [--gpu-sandbox-allow-sysv-shm](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=73): Allows shmat() system call in the GPU sandbox.
- [--gpu-sandbox-failures-fatal](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=76): Makes GPU sandbox failures fatal.
- [--no-sandbox-and-elevated](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/services/service_manager/sandbox/switches.cc?q=kNoSandboxAndElevatedPrivileges&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=90): Disables the sandbox and gives the process elevated privileges (Windows only).

---

### Sandbox

Sandbox leverages the OS-provided security to allow code execution that cannot make persistent changes to the computer or access information that is confidential. The architecture and exact assurances that the sandbox provides are dependent on the operating system.

- [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) implementation principles:

  - *Do not re-invent the wheel*: It is tempting to extend the [os](/questions/tagged/os) kernel with a better security model. Don't. Let the operating system apply its security to the objects it controls. On the other hand, it is just okay to create application-level objects (abstractions) that have a custom security model.
  - *Principle of least privilege*: This should be applied both to the sandboxed code and to the code that controls the sandbox. In other words, the sandbox should work even if the user cannot elevate to super-user.
  - *Assume sandboxed code is malicious code*: For threat-modeling purposes, we consider the sandbox compromised (that is, running malicious code) once the execution path reaches past a few early calls in the main() function. In practice, it could happen as soon as the first external input is accepted, or right before the main loop is entered.
  - *Be nimble*: Non-malicious code does not try to access resources it cannot obtain. In this case the sandbox should impose near-zero performance impact. It's ok to have performance penalties for exceptional cases when a sensitive resource needs to be touched once in a controlled manner. This is usually the case if the OS security is used properly.
  - *Emulation is not security*: Emulation and virtual machine solutions do not by themselves provide security. The sandbox should not rely on code emulation, code translation, or patching to provide security.
- [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [implementation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/sandboxing.md)
- [macos](/questions/tagged/macos) [implementation](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox/osx-sandboxing-design)

Comment: that "no-sandbox" flag should be avoided unless you absolutely need to use it.... especially if you are automating a site you have no control over.  (I know I've seen a lot of scraping code using that flag... very dangerous...)  Btw, the clipboard is accessible from inside the sandbox, but some browsers (maybe all now?) will prompt to allow a site to access it.  I think it's also very important to stress that the driver (and your selenium code) is outside of the sandbox (flag or no) so it could get malicious data from a web site and execute it.

Comment: @pcalkins Agreed