# Chrome failed to start in docker container using Selenium after upgrading to ChromeDriver v80 and Chrome v80

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have E2E tests running in a docker container. After Friday's update of selenium/node-chrome it would not work anymore. I have tried to use older versions of selenium/node-chrome but it won't work. I have very little experience with docker containers etc.

> Google Chrome 80.0.3987.106 <- Info gotten running command
>   google-chrome --version chromedriver-80.0.3987.106 <- Info gotten from
>   /opt/selenium/ folder.

Here`s how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM selenium/node-chrome:3.141.59
ENV NODE_VERSION 12.14.1

USER root

RUN apt-get -qqy update \
 && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install xz-utils \
 && apt-get -qqy autoremove \
 && apt-get -qqy clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/* \
 && ARCH= \
 && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
 && case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in \
    amd64) ARCH='x64';; \
    ppc64el) ARCH='ppc64le';; \
    s390x) ARCH='s390x';; \
    arm64) ARCH='arm64';; \
    armhf) ARCH='armv7l';; \
    i386) ARCH='x86';; \
    *) echo "unsupported architecture"; exit 1 ;; \
  esac \
  # gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-keys
  && set -ex \
  && for key in \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A \
    8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600 \
    4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C \
    A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762 \
    B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C \
  ; do \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done \
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" \
  && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
  && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
  && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
  && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs \
  && mkdir /src \
  && chown seluser /src

USER seluser

WORKDIR /src

COPY ./package-lock.json ./package.json ./
RUN npm install && \
  npm run wd:update

COPY . ./

CMD ["npm", "test"]
```

Build seems to go fine without any problems, but when trying to run tests I get the following error message:

```
    > protractor protractor.conf.js

[13:51:33] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:51:33] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[13:51:35] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://XXX.XX.X.X:51473/wd/hub
[13:51:36] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '8bc3b606ae46', ip: 'XXX.XX.X.X', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.76-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5584b6f867a9 <unknown>

[13:51:36] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '8bc3b606ae46', ip: 'XXX.XX.X.X', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.76-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5584b6f867a9 <unknown>

    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/src/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/src/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at /src/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/src/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/src/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (/src/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/src/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Local.getNewDriver (/src/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/src/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at /src/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (/src/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at /src/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/src/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[13:51:36] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: Why isn't the _chromedriver_ and _chrome_ version available within the logs?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea. This way of running tests was not implemented by me.

Comment: Okay, programmatically or manually can you pull out the version information of _ChromeDriver_ and _Chrome_, I suspect a mismatch

Comment: Google Chrome 80.0.3987.106 <- Info gotten running command google-chrome --version

chromedriver-80.0.3987.106 <- Info gotten from /opt/selenium/ folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
[13:51:36] E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '8bc3b606ae46', ip: 'XXX.XX.X.X', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.76-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_242'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5584b6f867a9 <unknown>
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver v80.0* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* with in *Docker image for Chrome (80.0)*.

---

As per the discussion [WebDriver 80.0.3987.16 can't open Chrome on Linux](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3336) @triciac mentioned that, the implementation of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) **v80.0** looks for *Chrome* in the following order:

1. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/usr/local/sbin"));
2. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/usr/local/bin"));
3. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/usr/sbin"));
4. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/usr/bin"));
5. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/sbin"));
6. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/bin"));
7. locations->push_back(base::FilePath("/opt/google/chrome")); // last try with the default installation location.

@johnchen confirmed that, the binary search order on Linux was accidentally changed by [r708243](https://crrev.com/708243), which was intended to make it easier to configure the name of the Chrome binary, but accidentally changed the search order as well.

*ChromeDriver* team have updated *ChromeDriver* to fix this issue through this [revision](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/424bb8bf09218e7ce1a56a90b379ec34b2f2a65a) / [commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/424bb8bf09218e7ce1a56a90b379ec34b2f2a65a).

---

### Solution

The above mentioned solution is available with:

- [ChromeDriver v80.0.3987.106](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=80.0.3987.106/)
- [ChromeDriver v81.0.4044.20](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=81.0.4044.20/)

---

### Interim solution

An interim solution would be using the `binary_location` **attribute** and you can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium: WebDriverException:Chrome failed to start: crashed as google-chrome is no longer running so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073411/selenium-webdriverexceptionchrome-failed-to-start-crashed-as-google-chrome-is/53078276#53078276)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. I have managed to get it working now. Altought I didnt use your Interim solution, but when reading throught links that you have provided, I noticed, that adding tag "--no-sandox" could help, and it did in my case. As mentioned by @johncen here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3336

Comment: @Tralots As a side note these are the reasons behind I don't suggest [`--no-sandox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101367/security-considerations-chromedriver-webdriver-for-chrome/60111052#60111052) right from the word go but only when it becomes necessary.