# WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages error with ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 and Chrome 80.0.3987.122

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

My local windows 10 computer update auto chrome version to 80.0.3987.122 (Build officiel) (64 bits)

I use https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.106/chromedriver_win32.zip

but now I have this error:

```
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'WX-PC123456', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x013A0C83+1707139]
    Ordinal0 [0x013068F1+1075441]
    Ordinal0 [0x0127DFC9+516041]
    Ordinal0 [0x012104C2+66754]
    Ordinal0 [0x0120CCE2+52450]
    Ordinal0 [0x0122BFD7+180183]
    Ordinal0 [0x0122BDDD+179677]
    Ordinal0 [0x01229D4B+171339]
    Ordinal0 [0x01211D4A+73034]
    Ordinal0 [0x01212DC0+77248]
    Ordinal0 [0x01212D59+77145]
    Ordinal0 [0x0131BB67+1162087]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0143A966+508998]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0143A6A4+508292]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0144F7B7+594583]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0143B1D6+511158]
    Ordinal0 [0x0131402C+1130540]
    Ordinal0 [0x0131D4CB+1168587]
    Ordinal0 [0x0131D633+1168947]
    Ordinal0 [0x01335B35+1268533]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x757E8674+36]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77475E17+311]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77475DE7+263]
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Use chromedriver 64 bits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'WX-PC123456', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_211'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x013A0C83+1707139]
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

It seems the issue is with  [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871),s [security feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101367/security-considerations-chromedriver-webdriver-for-chrome/60111052#60111052) of [Sandboxing](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/design/sandbox.md). To bypass this feature you can use the argument:

```
--no-sandbox
```

So your effective code block will be:

- Java

  ```
  options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); # Bypass OS security model
  ```
- Python

  ```
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
  ```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using

```
--remote-debugging-port
```

then try changing port number, it could be possible that port number you are using currently is already being used.